# Formation of intimate ion pair by halogenoalkanes

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution

I was recently doing this organic chemistry question that tested on the concept of the formation of the intimate ion pair in the nucleophilic substitution reaction at an $\ce {sp^3}$ carbon:

$\ce {RX -> R^+||X^- -> R^+ + X-}$

This mechanism is responsible for the slight retention of configuration during an $\ce {S_N1}$ reaction. It was mentioned that the formation of the ion-pair is more likely to occur for a chloroalkane than for a bromoalkane. In fact, it was written that there would be complete racemisation in the case of the bromoalkane while the chloroalkane would have slight preference for retention over inversion.

This seems to make sense since the $\ce {C-Cl}$ bond is stronger than the $\ce {C-Br}$ bond and secondly, the $\ce {Cl^-}$ ion is more charge-dense and is more likely to stay close to the carbocation after it is formed due to favourable electrostatic attraction. However, I have not read about this before from any authorative textbook on organic chemistry so I would just like to verify the validity of this assertion.

Also, can we extend this and assert that the formation of the intimate ion-pair is more likely to occur for bromoalkanes then for iodoalkanes based on a similar line of reasoning?

Comment: There's hardly any pure SN1 or SN2, you bring out one of the reasons. I think that something like intimate ion pair is always  made at the start of SN1 and the difference is, if it's broken by solvent before nucleophile attacks or not.